# Backbone.js and Todo Sample App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get my head around the Todo sample app for Backbone.js

While I have most of it understood there is one part I don't get and was hoping someone could explain for me.

Looking at https://github.com/jeromegn/localtodos/blob/master/javascripts/todos.js

Line 162: How does the "todo" parameter in the function get here? I can't see how it's sent or from where?

Any help would be much appreciated and yes I will credit good answers now I know how it works on this site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `AppView.initialize` method, on line 146, the `addOne` method is registered as an event handler for the `Todos` collection's add event.

```
Todos.bind('add', this.addOne);
```

When an item is added to the collection, Backbone triggers the `add` event, and passes the added model as the first argument to the event handler.

According to the [list of built-in events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog), the `add` event handler method is passed the following arguments:

```
"add" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.
```

That means that the `addOne` method could also receive two more arguments:

```
addOne: function(todo, todoscollection, options) {
    console.log(todo); // -> the model which was added
    console.log(todoscollection); // -> the collection, to which the model was added
    console.log(options); // -> the original options argument passed to collection.add
}
```

But because in Javascript declaring the full argument list is not necessary, the authors of the sample has chosen only to "receive" the first argument.

Comment: Ah brilliant - that explains it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

When some code calls that function, 'addOne', it needs to supply one parameter which will be named 'todo' inside the 'addOne' function. If you notice the 'bind' above, 'addOne' is also called for the 'add' event. If you look below, you see 'addAll' where the 'each' will supply the one element each time it calls 'addOne'

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I understand how the "addAll" function loops through the collection and calls the addOne but "addOne" can also be called directly from the bind. How is the model passed in this way?